# Windows 8 often shuts down when I leave it plugged in and running (while configured not to do so). How can I detect the issue?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

My Surface Pro 2 running Windows 8.1 shuts down at random times when I have it plugged in. It never shuts down when I'm using it, so I can't link the issue to a specific activity.

Is there an error log or some other method that I might be able to use to figure out what caused the shut down, when I wake up in the morning or come back to the house to find it shut down?

Here are my power settings:
[image]

Comment: The built in Event Viewer will allow you to view the system log entries - you can search for it in the Start screen.  Also, in these cases when the system is powered off, does Windows restart or resume?

Comment: @ernie neither. I have to turn it on from being totally off.

Comment: So when powering it up, does it state that it's recovering from an unexpected shutdown, or just boot as if you had shutdown normally?  The logs in Event Viewer are probably your best bet at this point . . .

Comment: @ernie it boots as if I had shut down normally. You should post that as the answer perhaps, so I can accept it. I'll utilize that tool now that I know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place to start digging would be the Windows Event Viewer (just search for this from your Start Screen).

In the Event Viewer, expand the Windows Log section on the left.  The Application and System logs are probably your best starting point . . . I'd look for the log entries for the known time you booted the system, and then scroll back, seeing if there's anything indicative of why the system powered down.